# Simple lookup on key for structs

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable, associative-array

Is there a way to implement the 'LookupFunc' in this code:

```
enum FoodType { FRUIT, VEGGIE, DESSERT };

struct Food {
    char name[20];
    int index;
    FoodType type;
};

struct Food APPLE = {"apple", 0, FRUIT};
struct Food CARROT = {"carrot", 1, VEGGIE};
struct Food CANDY = {"candy", 2, DESSERT};


struct Food f = LookupFunc("apple");
printf("indexof apple: %d\n", f.index);
printf("type of apple: %d\n", f.type);
```

I will have only 8 types of Food object/structs, but unlimited possibilities to search. Ideally, char name[20], would not be needed in my struct and it would go by variable name but I don't think C can do that. I have a feeling this may be easier by using multidimensional arrays and searching using a for loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `struct Food APPLE...` instead of `struct Opcode APPLE...`?

Comment: Yes sorry I fixed it now

Comment: Your intuition is right - C doesnt preserve any variable or field names at runtime so you will need to take care to store your values in datastructures that will let you search afterwards. The only suggestion I would add is that you might want to consider using an enum for the variable names/categories instead of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of `struct Food` like this:

```
#define MAX_FOODS (8)
struct Food foods[MAX_FOODS] = {
                                   {"apple", 0, FRUIT},
                                   {"carrot", 1, VEGGIE},
                                   {"candy", 2, DESSERT},
                                   ...
                               };
```

This way, it'll be easy to search and index.

```
int i = LookupFunc("apple");

int LookupFunc(char *str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_FOODS; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(foods[i].name, str) == 0)
            return i;
    }

    return -1; // Not found
}
```

Comment: Is array traversal the best option here given only 8 entries, it's not worth seeking out faster binary tree / hash table methods?

Comment: @BHare Yes, if the array gets sufficiently large, a different searching method should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as Fiddling Bits's answer, but with less hard coding

```
//define constant lookup table
const struct Food foodTable[] = {
    APPLE, CARROT, CANDY,
};
const int foodTable_len = sizeof(foodTable)/sizeof(Food);

Food LookupFunc(const char *foodStr) {
    for (int i=0; i<foodTable_len; i++) {
        bool strMatch = 0 == strcmp(foodTable[i].name, foodStr);
        if (strMatch)
            return foodTable[i];
    }

    //no match. Return something invalid
    return ?;
}
```

Also, to implement an efficient, large, read-only map, one can make a hash table and use a perfect (collision free) hash function. See the external links section on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)